# shopify embedded storefront frame gets "page not found"

Tags: facebook, frame, store, shopify

I have a Facebook App that displays our storefront in the page.  Up until 2 days ago the application was working fine.  AFAIK nothing changed either on the FB page or the storefront.  Now my FB app shows a "Page not found" error message.  The application is a storefront built with Shopify and the URL to the store is https://skydivesnohomish.myshopify.com/ which also works fine.  The Facebook application URL is https://www.facebook.com/pages/Skydive-Snohomish/452038620093?id=452038620093&sk=app_285458268248710

Please let me know if this is a known issue or how to debug it further.

Also found that Facebook appears to be issuing a POST to the page for some unknown reason.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? You need to be aware that your Shopify storefront does not run on https but only on http, which can be an issue if you are running it within an iFrame on a https site ;)

Comment: No, I ended up just using a 3rd party app to house the Shopify page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See final comment above - I ended up just using a 3rd party app to house the Shopify page.